# Triggering Lambda function when my application port is down

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

I want to trigger a Lambda function when my application port is down (application is running on Amazon EC2). So please let me know of any solution.

Comment: What do you mean by application port is down? you mean EC2 is stopped?

Answer (score 1):

If you intend to trigger a lambda based on EC2 events, you can set up a Cloudwatch Alarm for EC2 status checks (see [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/monitoring-system-instance-status-check.html)) which sends a message to SNS (see [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/AlarmThatSendsEmail.html)) which in-turn triggers a lambda (see [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-lambda-as-subscriber.html))

However, if you want to check an application is responding (e.g. a webserver) you'll have to configure a load balancer to do a health check on specific port of your server (or auto-scaling group) and set up Cloudwatch Alarms on these health checks rather than at instance level.

Comment: Another option _might_ be to create an Amazon Route 53 health check.